# What variations of WWW part from the URL's host name exist?

Tags: url, web

Most URLs on the web can begin with the `www.` part:

> http://www.example.com

or without it:

> http://example.com

But I remember I came across seeing something like this:

> http://www2.example.com

I need to know what types of the `www` part of the URL exist besides the ones that I listed above?

Comment: There is no set list, it's completely arbitrary.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Oh wow, so some server can have `vvv` instead, hah? The reason I'm asking is because some servers automatically remove the `www` part.

Comment: @c00000fd: Yes, pretty much anything can be used as a prefix like this.  In fact, there can be multiple prefixes.  There's nothing stopping a site from being vvv.www.fff.tt.yyy.sfserg.fvvnvnviuiuef.g.example.com

Comment: @c00000fd: The TCP/IP protocols that transport HTTP traffic don't know or care about hostnames.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about the [*third-level domain*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Second-level_and_lower_level_domains), typically called *subdomain*. In DNS speak it’s a *label*.

Such a DNS label can contain up to 63 characters, consisting of

- `a`-`z`
- `A`-`Z` (however, they are interpreted case-insensitive)
- `0`-`9`
- `-`

([Internationalized domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) would allow for more characters, but technically the same character set is used, see [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).)

Using `www` is a very common convention, but in no way required.

A popular example with a different subdomain is Wikipedia. The English Wikipedia has the hostname [`en.wikipedia.org`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), i.e., they use `en` (in their case representing the language code for English) instead of `www`.

Because `www` is so common and many people add it to all URLs when typing them, websites typically adapt to it: either by providing both variants (with and without `www`), or by redirecting from one variant to the other. (The latter is usually preferred because having canonical URLs is useful for many reasons.)

Note that domains don’t have to stop at the third level, you can have more levels, like `fifth.fourth.third.example.com`. Some sites even use the `www` convention for such domains, so they’d add `www` to any domain, e.g. `www.fifth.fourth.third.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It seems like there's no standard for that `www.` subdomain, is there?

Comment: @c00000fd: Nope. As I wrote, it’s only a convention. (And what should a standard define about this anyway?)

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. I'm just asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is something you configure in the webserver. Commonly, they contain a different site or are alias to the main site, taking into account typos the users may make, but yes, it is arbitrary.