# Use of dot ( . ) after www. in the URL

Tags: url

I often visit [a link](http://www.google.com/)!
But i have no idea what dot (.) represents in the URL.
What is use of dot (.) in the URL?

Answer (score 5):

The dot (`.`) is the character that was defined to be the delimiter in domain names (see [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)).

It delimits the [labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26092914/1591669) in a domain name.

The domain name `www.google.com` consists of three labels:

- `com` (aka. the top-level domain)
- `google` (aka. the second-level domain)
- `www` (aka. the third-level domain, or subdomain)

Comment: Agreed. To add to this it is similar to your mailing address at home. It starts with the most specific then goes to the most general (i.e. your name, followed by your street address, followed by your city, then state/province, then country). In a URL the dot represents each level from most specific to least specific similar to how a space, comma, or new line works in your mailing address.

Answer (score 0):

The '.' is like a character which differentiates from the domains. like www.todaysfuture.in the '.' after www means the first domain is done. then it checks the next domain.

The best example is like your email ID
first is the email-ID
then is the '@' that means the account name is done
then comes gmail/yahoo/wtvr
then a '.' to finish the account type
then '.' com or in depending on the account

Answer (score 0):

Web addresses, or Uniform Resource Locators, go backwards with more specific terms coming first (like real addresses).

So for `www.google.com`

- `com` is the top level domain - it might be a global domain like `.com` or a country code like `.uk`, and some top level domains have sub divisions like `.gov.uk` and `.co.uk`.
- `google` is the domain - this is the name you actually buy and route to your servers/services
- `www` subdomain - these are optional, and can be used to distinguish different services running on the same server, so `www.google.com` would serve web pages while `ftp.google.com` might be an FTP service.

Note that the subdomain is often optional - `google.com` and most other servers will assume `www` as the default service or infer it from the protocol (the `http://` bit).